# why stderr fails to be redirected using the 2>&1 instruction? and how outputs are expected to work?

Tags: bash, redirect, output

this fails stderr redirection:
`(echo a >/dev/stdout;echo b >/dev/stderr) 2>&1 >test2.log;ls test2.log;cat test2.log`
so, the above will output: "b" at terminal, and will log "a"

this fails to log stderr too:
`(echo a >&1;echo b >&2) 2>&1 >test2.log;ls test2.log;cat test2.log`

this vanishes with stdout and logs stderr:
`(echo a >/dev/stdout;echo b >/dev/stderr) &>test2.log;ls test2.log;cat test2.log`

this fully works:
`(echo a >&1;echo b >&2) &>test2.log;ls test2.log;cat test2.log`

is this some bug related to the way things should be outputted or I am missing some knowledge?

Obs.: I found this problem because I wasnt being able to log `strace dosbox`, this is NOT a dosbox question, this is just a comment to say that the origin of the problem was found on a non script application (could be any other application...), and I was able to replicate the problem on a command line terminal in a script way.

PS.: ubuntu 16.04.1 , bash 4.3.48(1)

Comment: Tip: [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically identifies [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2069).

Comment: @thatotherguy wow thats a holy graal! I have created a huge lot of scripts already and never used it! I am quite scared and happy at the same time as I will check them all there, thx vm!!! ( my low score prevents me from voting u up yet tho :( ), command line too! `sudo apt install shellcheck`

Comment: @thatotherguy as tip [from](http://net-hope.blogspot.com.br/2016/07/til-geany-and-shellcheck.html) we can use at `geany` menu `build/lint` on shell scripts, much easier with highlights for problems!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Wrong
(echo a >/dev/stdout;echo b >/dev/stderr) 2>&1 >test2.log
```

This first redirects stderr to where stdout is pointing: the console. Then it redirects stdout to `test2.log`. The second redirection doesn't affect the first. The end result is that stderr is still visible, it isn't logged.

```
# Right
(echo a >/dev/stdout;echo b >/dev/stderr) >test2.log 2>&1
```

Solution: swap the order of the redirections. Reading left to right, you want to redirect stdout to `test2.log`, and then redirect stderr to where stdout is pointing: `test2.log`.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to recognize that the shell first processes the redirections outside the subshell from left to write; the resulting file descriptors are then inherited by the subshell.

With this

```
(echo a >/dev/stdout;echo b >/dev/stderr) 2>&1 >test2.log
ls test2.log
cat test2.log
```

The shell starts by processing `2>&1`, which sends standard error to the same place as standard output (here, the terminal). The next redirection makes `test2.log` the standard output, without affecting standard error.

Now, the subshell inherits those file descriptors, so `a` is written to the inherited standard output (i.e., `test2.log`) and `b` is written to the inherited standard error (i.e., the terminal).

Comment: so, I did a double redirection of stdout, and left stderr pointing to the terminal?